# Combinations of ratios of 4 different numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have 4 different substances I have to mix in all possible combinations. Let's say that the max quantity per substance is 5000, and that every step is 1000. So a substance can appear in a combination as 0,1000,2000,3000,4000 or 5000.

I was planning do to a for loop, for the 4 substances, going from 0 to 5000 in all of them, but I am aware this will produce lots of duplicate results. For example, (1000,1000,1000,1000) is the same as (5000,5000,5000,5000)

How can I make all the combinations without repetition?

Answer (score 0):

First, determine howe much you shuold have in total.

Start with the first substance, add 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 or 100% of the total amount
Continue with the second substance, depending on how much you added of the first substance you can add 0%, up to (100% - first substance %) in 20% steps.
Continue with the third substances in the same way.
The forth substance fills up to 100%.